# HTMLUnit and Java: NoSuchMethodException: createDefaultSSLContext()

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have this HTMLUnit project and every time I try to build it it gives the following error: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext()`. I tried to search for a solution but the proposed approaches don't look right to me. The JVM I'm using is `Java SE 6 (MacOS X Default)` and even changing the compiler level from 1.6 to 1.7 or 1.5 doesn't solve the problem. I'm 100% sure the program runs on other machines, but I can't access their JVM to check. Do any idea on how to solve the issue?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem was neither in the JVM nor in the Apache jar at runtime. I downloaded a more recent version of HTMLUnit and this seemed to fix the problem. Hopefully if somebody has or had had the same problem, this can fix it.

Comment: which version you have used. I am using html unit 2.1.2 i have same issue

Comment: Please accept your own answer, because we are unable to close any other question as a duplicate of this question until someone accepts or upvotes an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when using HtmlUnit 2.12.  I upgraded to 2.15 and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext()
```

It is not JVM issue, It seems you have wrong version of apache jar in classpath at runtime. Make sure you have correct version of HttpClient jar at runtime.

Comment: hi, thanks for the quick reply. how can i make sure of that in Eclipse?

Comment: Runtime files will be in lib folder.

Comment: Thanks but no, I can only find .class files over there